# Debug JS Remotely not working for native-react(android) in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

When I try to connect to debugger, it throws following error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you set your debugger server in your device? [Here](http://blog.differential.com/intro-to-debugging-react-native-ios-and-android/) you have a tutorial. Usually, It must referece to: `http://your_pc_ip:8081`

Answer (score 7):

Browsed to http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui and then clicked 'Debug js remotely'.That got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Replace default react Ip with  localhost like this:

http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in the command line ?

More info here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue on windows, Press `CTRL + M`,

Go to `Dev Settings` and under Debugging menu click `Debug server host & port for device`,

Set it to `localhost: 8081`

Restart the App